# How can I read two values for the same request from CSV data set config in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to read two values from two different rows in a csv and pass those values as a part of the body of a POST request. 
Through CSV data set config I'm able to read only one value at a time. Is there any way I can read two values in the same request?

**Example**:
**sourceSystemGuid,sourceSystemName**

> sourceSystem_733,sourceSystem733 sourceSystem_590,sourceSystem590
>   sourceSystem_959,sourceSystem959

I need to read two values for `sourceSystemGuid` in one request.

Answer (score 0):

Without custom scripting it’s not possible.

But you can put 4 columns per line and that will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to know if the only way is scripting.

Comment: Hello, yes. If answer is ok you should accept it and upvote. Thanks